# win32api TextOut()

Tags: c++, winapi

When I write code for Windows several functions give me error message

> "undefined reference to ...",

for example `TextOut(...)` function generate

> "undefined reference to 'TextOut@20' ".

Example:

```
case WM_KEYDOWN ://cand apas o tasta
       {
          char szName[31];
          HDC  hDC;

          InvalidateRect( hWnd, NULL, TRUE );
          UpdateWindow( hWnd );

          hDC = GetDC( hWnd );
          GetKeyNameText( lParam, szName, 30 );
          TextOut( hDC, 10, 10, szName, lstrlen( szName ) );
          ReleaseDC( hWnd, hDC );
       }
       break;
```

I use **GNU GCC codeblocks - mingw Compiler**

Please,somebody tell me why I receive this error message?
Thank You.

Comment: Do you compile with unicode enabled? Have you checked if with `TextOutA` it compiles?

Comment: Try Visual Studio Community. Is free and is made for Windows.

Comment: Is your project linking to `Gdi32.lib`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your compile command - in particular, your link command (which is probably missing one or more libraries that you reference).

Comment: Thank' s to all. I downloaded SDK and then I linked GDI32.lib and now my code is working.

Comment: I disagree with the dupe, as there was a bit more to this specific problem than is addressed in the answers to the other question.  Voting to re-open.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol `TextOut@20` isn't exported from any library. The symbols are called `TextOutA` and `TextOutW` (with appropriate decoration). You are using header files that aren't compatible with the Windows API, and they fail to map `TextOut` to either `TextOutA` or `TextOutW`. Consider using the [official SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).

As an aside: The call to `TextOut` takes a `const TCHAR*`, not a `const char*`. If you wish to use a `char` array (you shouldn't), call `TextOutA`. It is recommended to use `wchar_t` arrays instead, and call `TextOutW`, though.